# Custom field in payment method section in Magento checkout onpage magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

I added a custom field on `order level` and want to display in payment section remember its not payment method its custom optional field but not showing this is my code

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
     <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Faq</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.payment">
        <block type="core/template"  after="methods" template="customponumber/customponumber.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: <checkout_onepage_index>
      
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.payment">
            <block type="core/template"  after="methods" template="customponumber/customponumber.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

Answer (score 0):

Just adding your block, within a reference to `checkout.onepage.payment` is not sufficient (and `after` will have no effect).

The first thing you should do is add a `name` to your block, like:

```
<block type="core/template" name="customponumber" template="customponumber/customponumber.phtml" />
```

Then, you will need to edit `template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`, within your current theme.

Within `payment.phtml`, look for `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>`, and add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customponumber') ?>` below it; like so:

```
// app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
...
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customponumber') ?>
...
```

You have to do this because the block you are referencing also uses a template, and does not automatically display all of it's children.